# Using "déjà vu" as an adjective

Tags: nouns, adjectives

Usually, I use the word *déjà vu* as a noun, e.g. "sense of déjà vu aroused by an experience".

But the sentence sounds somewhat passive this way and less interesting and also long. I couldn't find an adjective form of the word *déjà vu* to make the sentence more active like "déjà vu'*tic* experience".

How can I make use of the word and yet form my sentence in a more active and impactful manner without having too many "by"'s and "of"'s?

Comment: I’d certainly write it *déjà vu*, no matter what I did with it.

Comment: Thanks, I have updated my question with the correct type.

Comment: The adjective form of *déjà vu* is *déjà vu*. And there is most certainly no such thing as *déjà vu'tic*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Déjà vu is a word borrowed from French, a look into the dictionaries gives only one form, that is *Déjà vu*. It's a noun and seems there is no adjective form for this word. A little googling lead to this link which gives elaborate information on this word

http://sixthsensereader.org/about-the-book/abcderium-index/deja-vu/

Here it's said that *the original use* of the word was in adjective sense.

"Déjà vu crosswords, a little bit too Déjà vu for me"

By the above examples your sentence can be written as " ***Déjà vu experience***". This is just like the way we use *good*, *bad* etc as adjectives ( Good experience , bad experience etc)

Answer (score 3):

There is no adjectival form of *déjà vu*: the phrase literally means "already seen", with *vu* being the past particple of the verb *voir*, which means "to see". If you substituted the English, the correct way to incorporate it into a sentence  would be "an experience already seen" (i.e., "an already seened experience" would be incorrect).

If you wanted to use it before the noun, you could rely on the listener/reader accommodating the seemingly incorrect usage of *déjà vu* (i.e., "a déjà vu experience") or a neologistic formation (e.g., "a dejavued experience" or "a déjà-vued experience"), but it's probably going to be clearer if you use a different adjective that conveys the same meaning as the phrase.

To this end, the word you're likely looking for is *uncanny*. A usage attributed to Sigmund Freud, he speaks of it thusly in ["The Uncanny"](http://web.mit.edu/allanmc/www/freud1.pdf) (PDF):

> The subject of the “uncanny” is a province of this kind. It undoubtedly belongs to all that is terrible—to all that arouses dread and creeping horror; it is equally certain, too, that the word is not always used in a clearly definable sense, so that it tends to coincide with whatever excites dread. [...]  I will say at once that both courses lead to the same result: the “uncanny” is that class of the terrifying which leads back to something long known to us, once very familiar.